# RecyclerAdapter keeps reloading items every time I scroll - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

This is how I initialise my recycler

```
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

          final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

This is my Adapter:

```
    public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerHolder> {

    private List<MyRecyclerItems> recyclerItemsList;
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private int focusedItem = 0;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<MyRecyclerItems> listItemsList, ImageLoader imageLoader){
        this.recyclerItemsList = listItemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mImageLoader = imageLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public MyRecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int position){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_items, null);
        MyRecyclerHolder holder = new MyRecyclerHolder(v);

        holder.recyclerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                TextView redditUrl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url);
//                String postUrl = redditUrl.getText().toString();
//                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("url", postUrl);
//                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecyclerHolder holder, int position) {


        MyRecyclerItems listItems = recyclerItemsList.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);

        holder.getLayoutPosition();
        Log.d("adapter", "adapter called");

        holder.photo.setImageUrl(listItems.getImagePath(),mImageLoader);
        holder.email.setText(listItems.getEmail());
        holder.about.setText(listItems.getAbout());

    }

    public void clearAdapter(){
        recyclerItemsList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return (null != recyclerItemsList ? recyclerItemsList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

And this is how my logCat looks like:

```
    11-07 22:57:30.683 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:32.393 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:32.923 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:33.073 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:33.233 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:33.233 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 43 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 31 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:33.243 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:33.253 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:33.263 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
11-07 22:57:33.263 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 31 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:33.273 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:33.273 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
11-07 22:57:33.273 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:33.373 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42
11-07 22:57:33.623 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 31
11-07 22:57:33.883 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:34.403 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:34.583 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:35.143 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:35.653 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:36.093 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:37.173 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:37.463 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:38.253 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:38.413 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:38.433 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:38.433 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:38.433 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:38.433 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 31 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:38.883 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 31
11-07 22:57:38.963 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:39.993 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:40.483 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:40.483 22517-22802/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:40.483 22517-22802/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 31 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:40.503 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:40.503 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:40.503 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:40.503 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:40.513 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
11-07 22:57:40.513 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:40.513 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
11-07 22:57:40.513 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 46 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:40.713 22517-22803/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42
11-07 22:57:40.753 22517-22805/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 46
11-07 22:57:40.763 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:40.883 22517-22802/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 31
11-07 22:57:41.563 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:43.713 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:43.833 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/adapter: Adapter called
11-07 22:57:43.843 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-07 22:57:43.843 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 42 with tag a72673b100000000{2804315057,0} uid -1, pid: 22517, getuid(): 10804
11-07 22:57:43.893 22517-22804/name.company.newapp I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 42
11-07 22:57:44.233 22517-22517/name.company.newapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-07 22:57:45.653 22517-22517/name.company.newapp V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{22636519 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1f8bf54f {name.company.newapp/name.company.newapp.Recycler.RecyclerView}} show : true
```

Is this normal behavior ? As you can see from the logcat "Adapter called" appears a lot. The images are reloaded too, they get blank for a second and then reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is normal behaviour for RecyclerView. It optimises memory usage by only holding in memory the items that are displayed, and updates them with what is assigned in the onBindViewHolder method when it is displayed, normally seamlessly if you are loading in pre-cached data and resources.

What's happening here is that you have the line:

```
Log.d("adapter", "adapter called");
```

within your onBindViewHolder action, so every time that the item in your RecyclerView comes into view, this is called again. It's not actually the adapter being re-set on your RecyclerView, but the data being reloaded into that particular viewholder.

The image reloading that you are seeing is because you are throwing away the images and then reloading them every time that the ViewHolder is being scrolled/updated/shown on screen after being off screen. A better way to do this would be to load up all of your images into an LruCache, which Universal Image Loader [does if you switch it on](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info).